# How to manage groups, home directories and shell for Linux users authenticating via AD using SSSD?

Tags: linux, users, ldap, active-directory

I need to set up few Linux machines to have users authenticate to them via AD using SSSD, how do you manage the users groups, home directories and shell for the user accounts on AD, is there a way doing it on AD or I have to do it on Linux side and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have extended the Active Directory users account with POSIXAccount ObjectClass, you can set the loginshell and the homedirectory attribute on the Active Directory User Account.

For the Group Membership, the default Unix Group membership is defined by the GIDNumber attribute on the User Account. There should be a corresponding Active Directory Group with this GIDNumber. This group must be extended with the POSIXGroup Object Class.

Additional Active Directory groups can be defined with POSIXGroup Object Class with the user in those groups. The user can be in multiple POSIXGroup AD Groups. And these groups will be available on the Linux machines

Comment: Is this a reference to *Identity Management for UNIX*, the AD extended schema that provides a partially RFC 2307-compliant set of UNIX attributes? I loved it, but it's deprecated. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772571(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @Christopher I believe the POSIXGroup and POSIXAccount ObjectClass Schemas Extensions are still available for Active Directory

Comment: Also, if the homedir, shell, etc are sufficiently uniform, you can force the values directory with `override_homedir`, `override_shell`, `override_gid` in the sssd config.